# Create jQuery plugin with configuration settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been using the following design patter to create jQuery plugins.  I'm pretty sure I got the concept from the jQuery homepage, however, it appears to no longer be published there.

I recently attempted to access the `settings` variable within a method (i.e. `someOtherMethod ()`) other than the `init()` method, and experienced an error as `settings` was not defined.  I see the cause as `settings` is isolated to the `init()` method.

If I move `settings` outside of this method, I could then access it from different methods, however, each instance when the plugin is applied will not have its unique settings variable which is unacceptable.  For instance, `$('#id1, #id2').myPlugin({x:111});` should have a common `settings` variable, however `$('#id1').myPlugin({x:111}); $('#id2').myPlugin({x:222});` should each have their unique settings variable.

Given the below design pattern as a starting point, how can I access the `settings` variable from all methods associated with the plugin, yet have a unique `settings` variable each time the plugin is applied?

```
(function( $ ){

    var defaults={
        x : 123,
        y : 321
    };
    // var settings={}; //Should settings be defined here???

    var methods = {
        init : function( options ) {
            var settings = $.extend(defaults, options  || {});
            //settings = $.extend(defaults, options  || {}); //Should settings just be updated and not defined here?
            return this.each(function(){
                //whatever
            });
        },

        someOtherMethod : function() {
            return $(this).each(function(){
                //do whatever and use settings variable as applicable
            })
        },
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin' );
        }    
    };

}( jQuery ));

$('#id1, #id2').myPlugin({x:111});  //Sets x=111 in settings for both
$('#id3').myPlugin({x:333});        //Sets x=333 in settings.
$('#id3').myPlugin('someOtherMethod');  //Will have access to x=333 in settings.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to want to save the settings object per-element so that the settings will persist across different selectors. The best way to do this is to use [`jQuery.data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to attach a settings object to the element. This way, the settings will persist each time the element is selected, regardless of how it is selected.

Then, in the `.each` call of `someOtherMethod`, you can access this data using `jQuery.data` on the element.

Also, each individual element is going to need a separate settings object to avoid overwriting shared settings, so this:

```
var settings = $.extend(defaults, options  || {});
```

Will need to be replaced with this:

```
var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options  || {});
```

Otherwise the `defaults` object will be overwritten each time with new settings properties, and shared among all the elements.

In this example, I have created a variable name `internalPrefix` with the value of `'_myPlugin'` for the key under which to save the data using `jQuery.data`. I've added some tests at the bottom to show how it can be initialized on different ways, but the method can be called and still be aware of the settings used to initialize on the element.

#Working Example:

```js
(function( $ ){

    var defaults={
        x : 123,
        y : 321
    };
    //A variable to save the setting data under.
    var internalPrefix = '_myPlugin';

    var methods = {
        init : function( options ) {
            return this.each(function() {
                //Setup the settings object.
                var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options || {});
                //Save the settings to the element.
                $(this).data(internalPrefix, settings);
            });
        },

        someOtherMethod : function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                //Get the existing settings.
                var settings = $(this).data(internalPrefix);
                //Example:
                $('<code></code>').text(JSON.stringify(settings)).appendTo(this);
            })
        },
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin' );
        }
    };

}( jQuery ));

//Initialize the plugin different ways.
$('.group-1').myPlugin();
$('.group-2').myPlugin({
    x : 42,
    y : 1337
});

//Cal the methods on those different ways.
$('p').myPlugin('someOtherMethod');
```

```html
<p class="group-1">group 1</p>
<p class="group-1">group 1</p>
<p class="group-2">group 2</p>
<p class="group-2">group 2</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any reason I wouldn't just do `this.internalPrefix=settings;` instead of `$(this).data(internalPrefix, settings);`?

Comment: @user1032531 You could, but using `.data` is the jQuery way. Using `.data` keeps the property off of the DOM node, so it should not collide with other code. Some [old browsers would leak memory](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/memory/leak.html) if JavaScript objects were set as properties on DOM nodes, but any modern browser should be smarter than that.

Answer (score 1):

Updated, Added `{}` as first argument to [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

> If, however, you want to preserve both of the original objects, you
>   can do so by passing an empty object as the target:
>
> `var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);`

---

Try setting `defaults` as property of `methods` , defining `settings` within `init`

```
var settings = $.extend({}, methods.defaults, options || {});
```

setting `this` element `.data()` with `settings` before call to `.each()`

```
return this.data(settings).each(function() {})
```

`settings` would then be unique for each element ; accessible utilizing `$(this).data()` , returning `defaults` if `options` not passed as argument to `$.fn.myPlugin`, updating `defaults` if `options` passed as argument to `$.fn.myPlugin`

---

```js
(function($) {

  var defaults = {
    x: 123,
    y: 321
  };

  var methods = {
    init: function(options) {
      // extend `methods.defaults` with `options`
      var settings = $.extend({}, methods.defaults, options || {});
      return this.data(settings).each(function() {
        //whatever
        console.log("init", this.id, $(this).data());
      });
    },

    someOtherMethod: function() {
      return $(this).each(function() {
        //do whatever and use settings variable as applicable
        console.log("someOtherMethod", this.id, $(this).data());
      })
    },
  };
  // set `defaults` as property of `methods`
  methods.defaults = defaults;

  $.fn.myPlugin = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin');
    }
  };

}(jQuery));

$('#id1, #id2').myPlugin({
  x: 111
});
$("#id1").myPlugin({
  y: 222
});
$("#id2").myPlugin({
  y: 333
});
$("#id2").myPlugin("someOtherMethod");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z28wwnLh/1/

Comment: Thanks Guest.  Setting `defaults` as property of `methods` doesn't do anything different.  Furthermore, `this.data(settings)` is effectively just setting `x` and `y`, and will overwrite future instances.  http://jsfiddle.net/z28wwnLh/

Comment: @user1032531 See updated post. Provided `{}` as first argument to `$.extend()` within `init`.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this was a great answer, and like how you used ` return this.data(settings).each(function() {`.  I still don't think you needed to make `defaults` a property of `methods`, and it was what the same as the other answer, but a great answer never the less.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick stab but won't this work? or did i miss the point entirely?

```
(function ($) {

        var defaults = {
            x: 123,
            y: 321
        };

        $.fn.myPlugin = {
            init: function (opts) {
                var settings = $.extend(defaults, opts || {});
                $.each(settings, function (a, b) {
                    console.log(a, ':', b);
                });
            },

            someOtherMethod: function (opts) {
                var settings = $.extend(defaults, opts || {});

                $.each(settings, function (a,b) {
                    console.log(a,':', b);
                });
            }
        };
    }(jQuery));

    $('#id1, #id2').myPlugin.init({ x: 111 });  //Sets x=111 in settings for both
    $('#id3').myPlugin.init({ x: 333 });        //Sets x=333 in settings.
    $('#id3').myPlugin.someOtherMethod({ x: 223 });
    $('#id1').myPlugin.someOtherMethod({ a: 223 });
```

Comment: Thanks Dylan, but you are missing the point to some degree.  Only upon initial page load, an object needs to be passed to the plugin to configure it.